# Texto longo fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

Ola,

Estou tentando criar um contrato de prestação de serviço dentro do Dolibar CRM.

Ele trabalha com `fpdf`, e como não entendo quase nada, estou aqui.

Como todo contrato é grande, eu pensei em anexar um arquivo `contrato.php` com o contrato, e chamar no `pdf_strato.modules.php`, pois assim acho que ficaria mais fácil.

Minhas dúvidas são:

1. É possível fazer isto?
2. Vale a pena chamar `contrato.php`?
3. Como fazer isto?

Caso alguém tenho outra ideia, estou aceitando.

Obrigado;

kako.

Comment: vc esse contrato é gerado? uma string gigante?

Comment: este contrato é pré definido em um arquivo que preciso fazer para gerar pdf. As informações dos serviços e qualificação das partes já está resolvido. O que preciso é só texto formatado com artigos e parágrafos

Comment: Pensei até em inserir um arquivo contrato.doc já formatado

Comment: pode ser a inserção de um arquivo externo em html (contrato.html)

Comment: O "grande", você quer dizer, mais de uma página A4, isso?

Comment: sim, são 4 folhas A4. Já consegui fazer o tcpdf fazer as páginas dinamicamente, mas o problema é formatar as cláusulas do contrato que são fixas sem variáveis.
Se eu dividir os artigos em Cell() ou MultiCell() o problema é fazer continuar o texto como um parágrafo com a primeira linha recuada e as demais linhas acompanhando o texto do parágrafo.